# How do you bind an object returned from a factory to a method on an element?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-factory

I am learning how to use angular and I decided to split some code off into its own module to keep my main javascript file cleaner. I have everything working except for the binding part. Before I split it I had an element in my html file using `ngStyle` and I had a variable on my scope. I would call `$scope.$apply(function () { $scope.styles = { width: xxx }; })` when ever I set the variable on my scope and the element would update.

When I removed everything from my code and seperated it into a factory and directives I couldn't figure out how to do the same thing. I basically ended up with the code below and everything works except `ele`'s style tag does not update.

I wanted to use variables to hold the values and generate the styles object so I didn't have to do extra work myself, did I handle this correctly? If so, how can I make sure the element updates when `myFactory`'s `size` variable changes? If not, what would be a better way to handle this?

```
angular.module('test').factory('myFactory', function ($) {
    var size = 0;

    return {
        setSize: function (value) {
            size = value;
        },
        styles: {
            width: size + "px"
        }
    };
});

angular.module('test').directive('testDirective', ['myFactory', function (myFactory) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        link: function (scope, ele) {
            ele.css(myFactory.styles);
        }
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the working demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pyhvsdvt/2/) (Combining the answer of charlietfl and Exo).

In the factory, change the `styles` to be an object:

```
angular.module('test', [])
    .factory('myFactory', function () {
    var styles = {
        width: 100 + 'px'
    };

    return {
        setSize: function (value) {
            styles.width = value + 'px';
            console.log(styles);
        },
        styles: styles
    };
})
```

Then `$watch` the objects in the directive `link` function:

```
scope.$watch(function () {
    return myFactory.styles;
}, function (newValue) {
    ele.css(newValue);
}, true);
```

Comment: The only issue with this is that I need to access the number elsewhere, I was hoping to avoid having to parse it out

Comment: At least, you need some mechanism to **inform** the users of the factory: "Hey guys, I have changed the value, please update". `$watch` is to ensure the directive gets this message. I kind of cannot think of other ways except this mechanism (or similar).

Comment: Oh, maybe you want to use `events` (pub/sub) to control. But it needs extra code as well.

Answer (score 2):

The link function only runs once when the directive is added to the DOM. I assume you purposefully don't want to add elements to the DOM with this directive, so I would suggest trying something like:

```
angular.module('test').directive('testDirective', ['myFactory', function (myFactory) {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    link: function (scope, ele) {
      scope.$watch(function () {
        return myFactory.styles;
      }, function (newValue) {
        ele.css(newValue);
      }, true);
    }
  };
}]);
```

Comment: I had actually tried that verbatim but it didn't work either.

Comment: I didn't catch the issue with `setSize` that @charlietfl did. I think a combination of his code and the above code will allow updates to the factory to be reflected in the directive.

Answer (score 1):

Your `size` variable is a primitive so your width property won't update when you change it. The `styles.width` value will only be whatever it is when factory is initialized.

Change the setSize() function to actually update `styles.width`

```
 setSize: function (value) {
    this.styles.width = value + 'px';
  }
```

Now any scopes that are sharing this property will be updated also